# Getting a JSON response from Microsoft Live API instead of redirect for user's profile picture

Tags: json, rest, live-connect-sdk

I'm making the following request against the Microsoft Live API:

```
GET https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/picture?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

The result, unlike any other request to that API, is a redirect to a physical image location, which causes the actual image object to be returned instead of a typical JSON response that would include the path to that image.

I could dig into the the response object and try to get the `Content-Location` header or something to get the URL I'm looking for, but that feels very brittle and diverges from the way I'm handling every other API response.

I also know that the API URL itself, based on this behavior, can act as the image URL, but 1) I'm using a client that constructs that URL behind the scenes and 2) I don't want to persist the access token in something like a profile picture column.

The [Interactive Live SDK](http://isdk.dev.live.com/dev/isdk/ISDK.aspx) actually shows a JSON object as the return for a REST request:

```
{
    "location": "https://cid-0000000000000000.users.storage.live.com/users/0x0000000000000000/myprofile/expressionprofile/profilephoto:UserTileStatic"
}
```

That is the kind of response I want, and since the interactive SDK can show it, there's got to be some way to request that JSON be returned. I've tried setting `redirect=false` in the query string (necessary for Facebook, which does something similar) and setting the `Accept` request header to `application/json`. Neither had any effect.

Answer (score 1):

This is not truly an answer to my question, so I'd still be interested any responses along the lines of my original question. However, I have found a workaround of sorts.

The URL `https://apis.live.net/v5.0/{user_id}/picture` will return the appropriate photo photo without requiring an access token. Therefore, all you need is the the user's id to construct this URL, and that can be obtained via:

```
GET apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Which will return something akin to:

```
{
    "id": "0000000000000000",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "gender": null,
    "locale": "en_US"
}
```

The `id` member there, is what you need for the URL. It's not ideal, because I have to sort of do two steps, and hope Microsoft doesn't change the way the profile picture for a specific user is retrieved or suddenly starts requiring an access token for that too. It's better than nothing, though, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Adding ?suppress_redirects=true should do it.

i.e.
GET https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/picture?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&suppress_redirects=true

I actually haven't tested this with /me/picture, but {user_id}/picture has the same behavior and adding suppress_redirects=true did the trick.

Comment: Thanks. Once I have a chance to try this out I'll mark your answer as accepted if it works.